# Search DOM for special html tags without JQuery

Tags: javascript

I am working on make a project that requires looking for special tags on a page and then getting its attributes. An example of the tag looks something like this:

```
<ub:widget tag1="abc" tag2="doeraeme"></ub:widget:>
```

**WITHOUT JQuery**, how can I using Javascript search for each ub:widget and then collect their attributes individually?

Comment: Is `querySelectorAll()` an option? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getElementsByTagName` then `getAttribute`:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("ub:widget");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var widget = elements[i];
        var tag1 = widget.getAttribute("tag1");
        var tag2 = widget.getAttribute("tag2");
         alert("Found a widget! tag1 is " + tag1 + " and tag2 is " + tag2);
    }
}
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/DDREC/).

If you need it more generic i.e. don't have predefined tag name you can iterate all elements and look for those containing ":" in the tag name which usually means "special tag":

```
window.onload = function() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var curElement = elements[i];
        var curTagName = curElement.tagName.toLowerCase();
        if (curTagName.indexOf(":") > 0) {
            var widget = curElement;
            var message = "Found a widget! Tag name is: " + curTagName;
            if (widget.attributes.length === 0) {
                message += " without any attributes";
            } else {
                message += " with " + widget.attributes.length + " attributes: ";
                for (var j = 0; j < widget.attributes.length; j++) {
                    var curAttribute = widget.attributes[j];
                    message += "\n" + curAttribute.name + " = " + curAttribute.value;
                }
            }
            alert(message);
        }
    }
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DDREC/2/) with the generic approach.